# App-Only Microsoft Graph authentication with Microsoft.Graph library

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am successfully retrieving an access token for the Microsoft Graph API with the App-Only flow, but the produced token can't seem to access anything.

Here is the authentication code I'm using:

```cs
var clientApp = new ConfidentialClientApplication(
    identifier,
    authority,
    "urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob",
    new ClientCredential(secret), null, null);
var scopes = new string[] { $"{identifier}/.default" };
AuthenticationResult authResult = await clientApp.AcquireTokenForClientAsync(scopes);
return authResult.AccessToken;
```

From that, I do indeed get a token, but when I try to use it, it throws `Access token validation failure.` Here's the test query I've been using:

```cs
var users = service.Users.Request()
    .Filter($"mail eq '{resourceIdentifier}'")
    .Top(1)
    .GetAsync();
users.Wait();
```

For the API `baseUrl`, I was providing: `https://graph.windows.net/{appId}`. I did add `api-version=1.6` to the query string (manually, as I don't see an option exposed through the Microsoft.Graph NuGet library). I had earlier tried `https://graph.microsoft.com/v2.0`, also to no avail.

Anyway, given the error messages about `validation failure,` I have come to believe that our (possibly tenant-specific?) API URI might be wrong. Could that be it? What am I not seeing?

**Update**

The solution had two components. The first was as mentioned in the accepted answer. The second was that the scope should be, simply, `https://graph.microsoft.com/.default`, despite my API calls being tenant-specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're conflating two different APIs here.

The `graph.windows.net` URI is for the Azure AD Graph which is an entirely different API. For Microsoft Graph the URI should be `graph.microsoft.com`.

There is also isn't a `/v2.0` of Microsoft Graph today. The publicly available versions are `/v1.0` and `/beta`. Also note that when using the [Microsoft Graph Client Library for .NET](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet) you shouldn't need to provide a `baseUrl` as it already defaults to `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0`.

Comment: Thanks, @Marc. Those URLs were sort of wild haymakers after first using the default (`/v1.0`, by leaving it unspecified). The default throws the same error message for me, though. Any other thoughts about what could throw an invalid token error? I'm using a tenant-specific login: `https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/adminconsent`.

Comment: `/adminconsent` isn't used for authentication, that is only used to provide consent. After you have consent you need to pass your app credentials to the `/token` endpoint to receive an Access Token.

Comment: Beware online documentation. The `/adminconsent` suffix was the recommended URL for login by some blog for app-only flows with scopes requiring admin. Anyway, I got it working, and login does seem to work with or without `/adminconsent` appended to the URL, so who knows. For now, I've removed it per your advice. However, the other piece to the puzzle was that my scope should have been `https://graph.microsoft.com/.default` despite my queries being tenant-specific. I'll update my question with that.

Comment: Glad you got it working. Just to clarify, the URL should be `https://login.microsoftonline.com/{common or tenant id}/oauth2/v2.0/token`. I'm sorry I missed the error in your scopes but you are correct. The scope `https://graph.microsoft.com/.default` tells the system to use whichever scopes you pre-configued in your registration at `https://apps.dev.microsoft.com`.

Comment: @ChrisD , {tenant} - what is this?  It's not my app client id or my app name.  I can't find any documentation anywhere telling me _what it is_

Comment: The tenant's id. This is either the GUID used to identify the AAD tenant or the registered domain for the AAD tenant (i.e. `tenantname.onmicrosoft.com`).

Comment: Once I finally got the token, I discovered I can't use it for my endpoint, _a request is made to an endpoint that requires user sign-in_  I just wanted programmatic read access to an e-mail account (from a test), but I guess that's impossible.